# Query with sum of nested relationship based on reference id (laravel vue)

Tags: laravel, vue.js

With models

**Customer**
`id | name | code | ....`

**Project**(One customer can have many projects,One project can have many report)
`id | customer_id | name | code | ....`

**Report** (One project can have many report.the report is update each month)
`id | project_id | amount | year | month | ....`

How can I calculate the sum of column amount latest record of report based on reference `customer_id` ? I dont know how to make it work.

Any help will be appreciate. I want to display the sum of amount in latest report(latest report based on the reportid)  of each project based on customer id.

I have manythrough relationships set.

```
public function report()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            Report::class,
            Project::class,
            'customer_id', 
            'project_id', 
            'id',
            'id' 
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following will solve your problem:

In your `User.php` file:

```
public function reports()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        Report::class,
        Project::class,
        'user_id', 
        'project_id', 
        'id',
        'id' 
    );
}

public function projects(){
    return $this->hasMany(Project::class);
}

public function amount(){
    return $this->projects()->get()->sum(function ($project) {
        return $project->latestReport()->amount;
    });
}
```

In your `Project.php` file:

```
public function reports(){
    return $this->hasMany(Report::class);
}

public function latestReport(){
    return $this->reports()->latest()->first();
}
```

And finally. you could get the sum of amounts of the latest report for each project by calling:

```
User::first()->amount();
```

Comment: Hi, i try but it return blank in response..

Comment: If the Customer is same as User

Comment: Sorry, I answered the question considering the User is Customer, If you add the relations mentioned in the answer to Customer model it will worked

Comment: yeah, it is same but it does not return anything. it return html from in response panel

Comment: Are you sure that you have enough records in your database ?

Comment: At least you must have one customer that has at least one project that has at least one report

Comment: I implemented my answer before submitting it and everything work fine,.. Would you please try this code: ```Project::first()->latestReport()``` to check if the project returning the latest report

Comment: could you share some screenshots of your code to solve your problem ?

Comment: the project return the latest report

Comment: i have add the code in the post

Comment: Hi, or can discuss in the chat?

Comment: ok, but could we use stackoverflow chat ?

Comment: okok. can u create a chat?because I cannot create